loading matplot from pkl data
I have a problem with matplotlib. I got from my Company a couple of graphs as .pkl data and try to open them now.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle

with open('Inventar_plot_quantil_10.pkl','rb') as f:
   fig = pickle.load(f)

show()

but I got an error

Can't get attribute 'SubplotParams' on <module 'matplotlib.gridspec' from '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/gridspec.py'>

where is my mistake?
it should not matters that I use Linux and the graphs are from Mac, right?
Cheers
Lukas

I do not know if it's possible to pass pickle objects between different operating systems, but the package versions you are using definitely do matter.  In this case, it looks like you are trying to load using a different Matplotlib version than it was saved with: SubplotParams moved to a different module at v3.9.
